# Did Cinderella say something bad when the horses hit each other?

Tags: dialogue, cinderella-2015

So I watched the 2015 *Cinderella* movie a few times, and noticed that when Ella meets the prince in the forest and the horses hit each other's head Ella says something out of shock.

I listened closely and it sounds like some bad word that rhymes with ...truck, can someone enlighten me and say otherwise.

I would like to know what she says.

Comment: You have a link, or at least a timestamp?

Comment: If you mean the beginning of [this clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OdJhNA2qiHc), it sounds like 'What...?'

Answer (score 2):

The [film transcript](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=cinderella-2015) suggests not.

> CINDERELLA: Easy! Easy!  Whoa! Whoa! Easy, boy! Come on, boy, slow
>   down!
>
> PRINCE: Miss! Miss! Are you all right? Hold on!
>
> CINDERELLA: I'm all right, thank you!

And having listened to [the scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OdJhNA2qiHc) multiple times, there doesn't appear to be a swear, just Cinderella grunting "huh".

---

That's not to say that there hasn't been [swearing in Disney movies](http://hoaxes.org/weblog/comments/f_word_in_enchanted) before, just not in this case.